# plotly does not render xaxes range breaks with domains

Tags: plotly

Am trying to get plotly to generate graphs within three domains in Y-axis. The following code shows plotly graph.

These are the variables with imports

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import plotly.graph_objects as go
days = 50
date = pd.date_range('20210101', periods=days)
y1 = np.random.uniform(low=10, high=20, size=(days,))
y2 = np.random.uniform(low=5, high=10, size=(days,))
y3 = np.random.uniform(low=8, high=20, size=(days,))
```

Moving on to generate traces

```
# traces
trace1 = dict(name='y1', type='scattergl', 
            x=date, y=y1, yaxis="y")
trace2 = dict(name='y2', type='scattergl', 
            x=date, y=y2, yaxis="y2")
trace3 = dict(name='y3', type='scattergl', 
            x=date, y=y3, yaxis="y3")
```

Putting these in data

```
data = [trace1, trace2, trace3]
```

Building the layout

```
layout = dict(xaxis=dict(rangeselector=(dict(x=0, y=1, visible=True, buttons=[dict(step='all'), dict(step='month', count=1, label='1mo', stepmode='backward')]))),
              yaxis=dict(domain=[0.4, 1], visible=False), 
              yaxis2=dict(domain=[0.2, 0.4], showticklabels=False), 
              yaxis3=dict(domain=[0, 0.2], showticklabels=False), 
              legend=dict(x=0.3, y=1.08, orientation='h'), 
              margin=dict(b=40, l=40, r=40, t=40),
              )
```

Getting the figure to show

```
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
fig.update_layout({"xaxis": {"rangeslider": {"visible": False}}})
fig.update_layout(hovermode='x unified')
```

...but if I add to the axes

```
fig.update_xaxes(rangebreaks=[dict(values=date[-2:].astype(str).to_list())])
```

plotly doesn't show. Where am I going wrong? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- have simplified figure building test **rangebreaks**
- this works with **Scatter** but not **Scattergl** trace type

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([y1,y2,y3]).T, columns=["y1","y2","y3"], index=pd.date_range('20210101', periods=days))

go.Figure([go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df[c]) for c in df.columns]).update_xaxes(rangebreaks=[{"values":["2021-01-17"]}]).show()
go.Figure([go.Scattergl(x=df.index, y=df[c]) for c in df.columns]).update_xaxes(rangebreaks=[{"values":["2021-01-17"]}]).show()
```

Comment: Strange but true. The issue seems to be with `scattergl`.